# Hide product 'C' AND 'D' when product A is present

Tags: cpq, steelbrick, pricerule

I need to create a rule in salesforce CPQ, that hides product 'C' and 'D' when product A is selected.
I have created a selection rule. I am not sure if I shd use a configuration attribute or summary variable in this case.

Do I need to create a configuration attribute too in this case?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to run your rule in real-time: when user selects product A, then rule should be triggered and hide two other products. There are two fileds on Product Rule called `Apply Immediately` and `System` (I don't see them on your layout). These are checkboxes, when True they make your rule to be run every time user makes changes (select/deselect product).
Please remember that Evaluation Event of that Product Rule should be `Always`.

No need in configuration attribute in this case.

Here is a link to the [relevant documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.cpq_product_rule_guidelines.htm&type=5)

> To make a selection rule that functions in real time, select Apply Immediately and System on the product option that you want to function in real time. We recommend setting your selection rule’s Evaluation Event field to Always to ensure that the real-time processing happens throughout anything you do in the quote line editor.